# Excel - List data from 4 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel sheet where I want to make a list based on data in 3 columns. See the image for how the basic things looks currently.

[image: Example of data]

I have names in column A and then in column B,C and D is a mixture of colours.

How can I get excel to list the names of those who choose for example Red despite Red possibly being in B,C or D? So it looks a little like:

- Harry Red
- Sara Red
- Sue Red

When it's finished it will have something like 2500 rows and "colour" choice of 27.

The output hopefully would look like this image with the ability to choose which colour it looks for

[image: Output view]

Comment: can you give more information about the desired output? maybe an image showing what the output would be in excel?

Comment: Something like http://i.stack.imgur.com/tOjYn.jpg would be great with the ability to choose the colour it looks for

Comment: you need to un-pivot your data first (there are plenty of tips for that even this site), then just create a pivot table and filter for your desired colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a "helper column" to gather all the names associated with the colour *Red* without using array functions.  In **E2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(B2="Red",C2="Red",D2="Red"),1+MAX($E$1:E1),"")
```

and copy down.  Then in some other cell enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),E:E,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

The "helper column" identifies the rows of interest.  Other colours can be handled in a similar fashion.